# Can't connect SchemaCrawler to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-diagramming, schemacrawler

I've downloaded SchemaCrawler for the express intent of creating a database diagram for a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The details of my database (in SQL Server language) are:

```
Server Name:    localhost\SQLI03
Database Name:  TBL_DEV_53
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

I'm running the following SchemaCrawler command:

```
sc.cmd -c graph -host=localhost\SQLI03 -port=1433 -database=TBL_DEV_53 schemacrawler.Main -infolevel=detailed -schemas=dbo -tabletypes=TABLE -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=database-diagram.pdf %*
```

And 2 things are happening that I'm unable to resolve:

1. It's prompting me for a password.
2. It's outputting the following error:

> ```
> schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerSQLException: Could not connect to jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://.\SQLI03:1433/TBL_DEV_53;appName=SchemaCrawler;useCursors=true, with properties {}
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ashby,

Please change to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", using instructions in
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Then you can use "sa" as the user, and the password that you chose.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler